# PHP $_SESSION - some values retained, others lost during page submit

Tags: php, post, session-variables

`$_SESSION` is successfully maintaining some fields across a page submit process, but ONLY those that are specifically conserved in my own, self-created `$_SESSION` initialisation function.

This would not be odd if my `$_SESSION` initialisation function was actually being called .. obviously!!  Its whole purpose is to retain some key values, and wipe all the others from the `$_SESSION` array

**However, this happens even when that function is NOT called by my code.**

I have a View page including a form that is submitted, identifying a Control action file to trigger on submit.

I verify `$_SESSION` contents as part of the View page display. It displays the full set of `$_SESSION` array fields

I then do a `print_r` of `$_SESSION` contents immediately following `session_start()` in the identified Control file

Prior to the user hitting submit, the full set of `$_SESSION` values are there
Immediately after user hitting submit, most of them are gone, but anything I choose to retain on `$_SESSION` initialisation is retained.

NONE of my own code can possibly be running in between: there is pure PHP only there.

I had 2 theories on this.
 1. PHP does something in the background and happens to have an internal function name that I used by mistake, which was then calling my function in preference to the system function of the same name, thus resulting in my `$_SESSION` getting initialised.

So I changed the `function name (to clean_session())` -> same problem

2. Something about running the function when I initialise the `$_SESSION` upfront at the start of the application is giving those fields within the `$_SESSION` array a different set of properties from other fields which are added later.  As a result, only those fields are surviving a generic loss across the page submit.

Option 2 seems like the only even potentially non-insane answer.
Does anyone know if that is even remotely possible?

Or alternatively what else could be happening?

Comment: Option 1 is impossible, PHP won't let you create a function that conflicts with a built-in function name. There's no way to help you without seeing code, update your answer showing what you are doing.

Comment: Option 2 is impossible. variables stored in the session have no `properties` they are just values in an assoc array. **Show your code,** your code must be doing something to remove these variables, there is no magic involved

Comment: Thanks for confirming ... I'm clutching at straws.  The whole point here is that I can't show my code, because there **is** no code between the point where before submit it displays correct (full) session variables, and the point where after submit it has lost important fields.  Worse, from the same page, it loses session info with one button, but not another.  Both are 'submit' type and use the same form, with the same file for action. Info is lost BEFORE any processing based around which button was selected (straight after session_start).  I'm going mad here.

Comment: The problem happens whether I use POST or GET methods.  Previous comment about different buttons not quite true.  First submit of View page loses info.  If I use browser back button and resubmit (same page, same submit process) the info is retained the second time.  To be clear: `print_r($_SESSION)` is the last line in the View page. `print_r($_SESSION)` is the second line in the action file, immediately following `session_start()`.